# Deleting a 'No such file or directory' file

Tags: terminal, hard-drive, trash, macos

I recently swapped out the CD drive on my Macbook Pro late 2011 for a hard drive. On that hard drive there were some files that I wanted to delete, as per usual I moved them to the Trash. Now that they're in there they can't be deleted because due a to a message saying that the "*folder* is currently still in use". I located the folder to be on my newly added hard drive in its /.Trashes/ folder. I accessed this directory through the terminal and executed the command "sudo rm -rf /.Trashes/", however upon execution the message "No such file or directory" is noted after each of the folders within. I keep reading that this problem is something to do with 32 bit and 64 bit architecture confusion but if I'm honest I don't really understand what this means.

There is no option to reinstate the folder in the Trash ("Put back") and I can't forcefully remove the folder on my new hard drive that is stopping it from being in use. I've also accessed my /.Trash/ folder on my OS hard drive and done the same command ("sudo rm -rf /.Trash/") with no such luck.

Does anyone have any idea how I can go about deleting these files so they're removed from my trash and new hard drive?

Comment: Have you restarted and tried to normally delete the folders. By the way, /.Trash/ is on your main HD, and an external one would be /Volumes/DiskName/.Trashes/

Comment: Did you try `sudo rm -rf ~/.Trash/` instead of `sudo rm -rf /.Trash/`? This might help.

Answer (score 1):

Removing a .Trashes directory or a .Trash directory is the wrong approach. You want to just remove the files and directories within your .Trashes or .Trash directory. Assuming your shell is `bash` you can list those file system objects in your `.Trashes` directory with `find`. In this example the secondary hard drive is named backup.

```
find /Volumes/backup/.Trashes/"$UID" ! -name "$UID"
```

If the results are the files you wish to delete then you can add `-delete` to the `find` statement. Please be very careful applying this option.

```
find /Volumes/backup/.Trashes/"$UID" ! -name "$UID" -delete
```

For files in your home folder's .Trash directory

```
find ~/.Trash ! -name .Trash -delete
```